# how to use jquery make this?

Tags: jquery

```
http://www.lingerie.com/
```

how to use jquery to make the `LATEST NEWS:` part which on the toppest of the page.

[image]

supposed the html code is:

```
<ul id="latest">
<li><a href="#">example one</a></li>

<li><a href="#">example two</a></li>

<li><a href="#">example three</a></li>

<li><a href="#">example four</a></li>

<li><a href="#">example five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want to get the flash move of the five title.i don't know how to make an interval  between the two title. when one hide another shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this is to set up an interval loop which periodically hides the last shown element and displays the next one.  CSS can be used to start all of the items out as hidden.

CSS:

```
#latest a { display: none }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval((function() {
        var index = -1;
        return function() {
            var all = $('#latest a');
            if (index >= 0) {
                all.eq(index).hide();
            }

            index++;
            if (index == all.length) {
                index = 0;
            }

            all.eq(index).show();        
        };
    })(), 1000);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZNj6/1/

Comment: thank you, i can't follow the first parameter of the setInterval function well. could you explain it with more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at their source code using Firebug or Developer Tools for Chrome / IE / etc.

Look at the sc-scripts-2010.js file for the code for the news ticker (search for "news ticker").